I wanted to know if it was possible to get views into SSMS from Power apps Dataverse tables
I have been seraching this everywhere and was not able to find a solution anywhere and was wonddering if is it even possible?
The sitaution is that i have Datverse tables created in my power apps solution and i want to view these tables na dthe views of these tables that i created in SSMS so that i could calculations and logics in SSMS
Even though i can view the tables by connecting to the Power Apps environment using it as a Datbase engine is SSMS.
However, i am not able to see the views i careted for these table sin SSMS or even in Azure Data Studio.
I tried creating new tabels and views and even loading tables from new Environmnets nothing seems to work to show up the views in SSMS or any other Database Engine for that matter.
Can someone help me with this.
Any Help would be appreciated.
Many Thanks
Sai

check this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/maker/data-platform/azure-synapse-link-pipelines?tabs=synapse-analytics#use-the-solution-template
